# Restarting Shell functions in predetermined periods of time

Tags: linux, bash

Hope to be posting in the correct forum this time!

I have the following shell script triggered in my .xinitrc, which is used to form a info-bar in DWM. Consider the **xsetroot** function as a 'main echo'. My intention is to refresh the 'clock' each second, and the other values according to the sleep time set in their respective functions. I'm new to shell, but I believe it is not working as expected since the clock is being updated from second to second regardless of the sleeping time passed at the function "BATTERY". From what I understand, the clock should be updated after the previous sleeping time set in earlier functions, which only happens if I pass the time in seconds instead of dates to sleep.

In short: The CLOCK( ) function should be reloaded from second to second, the CALENDAR( ) should be restarted once a new day begins and so on...

How can I achieve the desired result (different reloading times for each function)? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Welcome Message
if [[ $(date '+%p') == AM ]]
then
        notify-send "Good Morning foo!"

elif [[ $(date '+%p') == PM && $(echo $(date '+%I')) > 06 ]]
then
        notify-send "Good Evening foo!"

else 
        notify-send "Good Afternoon foo!"
fi

# Battery percentage
BATTERY () {
        # I know that this battery info code is wrong. :p
        ONE_MINUTE= $(( $(date -d "00:01:00" "+%s") - $(date -d "00:00:00" "+%s") ))
        echo "$(acpi -b 0 | grep -o '....$')"
        sleep $ONE_MINUTE
}

# Network Connection
NETWORK=$(nmcli networking connectivity check)

# Clock + Calendar function
CLOCK () {
        echo "$(date '+ %I:%M:%S %p ')"
}

CALENDAR (){
        TIME_UNTIL_NEXT_DAY= $(( $(date -d "23:59:59" "+%s") - $(date "+%s") ))
        echo "$(date '+ %a %d/%m/%Y')"
        sleep $TIME_UNTIL_NEXT_DAY
}
```

Comment: This is no forum.

Comment: Try [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: `echo "$(...)"` is a useless use of echo.

Comment: Link for KamilCuk's "useless echo" comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2005

Comment: @ceving Thanks for the tips, I was unaware of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run work periodically, run it in a loop:

```
while true; do
    work_to_do
    sleep 30min
done
```

To run work periodically, you can also use `systemd.timer` functionality.

To run work periodically, you can use `cron`, if it's running. You can setup work non-interactively by editing `crontab -e`.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of crontab! What I did is basically the following: In the original script a variable takes the output of CALENDAR and BATTERY. BAR=" $(BATTERY) $SEPARATOR $(CALENDAR)" while true; do         xsetroot -name " $BAR $SEPARATOR $(CLOCK) " done As shown above only the clock gets ticked. Then I created 2 events that happen each minute. One kills the script, and the other starts it * * * * * kill $(ps -aux | grep dwm_bar.sh | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }') * * * * * sh ~/scripts/dwm_bar.sh

Comment: The only problem with directly timing a 1 sec tick is the processing that results in the second not being exactly 1 second. This can result in your clock skipping a second every so often. For a clock, you generally want to respond to a clock generated interrupt to determine when a new second is ready to display. To do this in bash, you need to balance between wasting clock cycles checking, and missing the event when sleeping. A balance is to save the current number of seconds and then do somethign like `while [ "$second" -eq "$clock_second" ]; then sleep .1; continue; # update clock; done`

Answer (score 0):

To have multiple "timers" running simultaneously, put them in the background and use the bash `wait` command. It's helpful to kill the backgrounded processes when the main script exits.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

clock() { date "+%F %T %Z"; }
battery() { echo battery check; }
calendar() { echo daily stuff; }

pids=()

while true; do clock; sleep 1; done &
pids+=($!)

while true; do battery; sleep 1m; done &
pids+=($!)

while true; do calendar; sleep 1d; done &
pids+=($!)

trap 'kill "${pids[@]}"' EXIT

wait
```